# Question regarding space transformation in special relativity

Tags: special-relativity, spacetime, coordinate-systems

While learning about Special Relativity I learnt that we use the Transformation matrix to alter the space .This matrix differs for $Contravariant$ and $Covariant$ vectors.Why does it happen?,Why one kind of matrix ($Jacobian$) for $basis$ $vectors$ and other kind($Inverse$ $Jacobian$) for $gradient$ ,$divergence$ etc.Why does the matrix change ,why does changing quantities require a new matrix and why does $Inverse$ $Jacobian$ satisfy this?

$My$ $understanding$ $of$ $how$ $Jacobian$ $achieves$ $this$:

https://youtu.be/bohL918kXQk

Here Grant says that by moving a small dist $\partial x$ ,we produce a change in $\partial f_1$ direction and $\partial f_2$ direction , $\partial f_1$ in being $x+\sin(y)$ direction  & $\partial f_2$  being in $y+\sin(x)$ ,(ie) $\hat{x}$  transforms to $x+\sin(y)$ and $\hat{y}$ axis transforms to $y+\sin(x)$, by moving a small distance  $\partial x$ in $x$ axis in input we produce a effect on both the axes in output space, similar thing happens in y direction .

$$(x,y) \rightarrow (x+\sin(y),y+\sin(x)) $$
[image: Moving a small distance DX in x direction]

[[image: Moving a small distance <span class=]$\partial x$ in x direction in input space (input direction) causes a change in both the axes in output space" />](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ilUw3.jpg)

$$
J = \begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial f_1}{\partial y} \\
\frac{\partial f_2}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial f_2}{\partial y} \\
 \end{bmatrix}
$$

Is my interpretation a right one?

And why does the $Jacobian $ Matrix change for covariant and contravariant vectors?

Answer (score 0):

For a small distance, the coordinates
$$
\left(\begin{matrix}\hat x\\ \hat{y}\end{matrix}\right)=\left(\begin{matrix}f_1(x,y)\\ f_2(x,y)\end{matrix}\right)=:f(x,y)
$$
change by
$$
\left(\begin{matrix}\Delta \hat x\\ \Delta \hat y\end{matrix}\right)=J\cdot \left(\begin{matrix}\Delta x\\ \Delta y\end{matrix}\right)\,.
$$
That's the transformation law for contravariant vectors. Conversely, by the chain rule,
\begin{align}
\partial_{x}(F\circ f)&=
((\partial_{\hat x}F)\circ f)\,\partial_x f_1+((\partial_{\hat y}F)\circ f)\,\partial_x f_2\\[3mm]
\partial_{y}(F\circ f)&=
((\partial_{\hat x}F)\circ f)\,\partial_y f_1+((\partial_{\hat y}F)\circ f)\,\partial_y f_2\,.
\end{align}
This can be written as
$$
\nabla (F\circ f)=J^\top\cdot ((\hat\nabla F)\circ f)
$$
or as
$$
\nabla =J^\top\cdot\hat\nabla\,.
$$
This is the transformation law for covariant vectors (gradients).